# Really weird python error

Tags: python

```
...
def splitMunipulation(p,threshold=5000):
    runs=[];i=0
    while i<len(p):
        l=[];i+=1
        print i,p[i]
        while p[i]!=press(0,1,0):
            l.append(p[i]);i+=1
        else:       
            runs.append(l)#here i points to another (0,1,0)
    return runs
...

record=splitMunipulation(record)
```

'''

Output:

```
    1 <__main__.press instance at 0x046690A8>
      File "H:\mutate.py", line 28, in splitMunipulation
        while p[i]!=press(0,1,0):
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

`press`is a  class

and since `print p[i]` works well,why `p[i]` is considered out of range?

Really don't get what's going on

'''

Comment: The traceback you've posted doesn't match any line of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while p[i]!=press(0,1,0):
   l.append(p[i]);i+=1
```

The variable `i` gets incremented in this loop until `p[i]!=press(0,1,0)`. Since nothing is happening to make `p` longer, or to test that i is not greater than the length of p, it is easy to see how the index could get out of range.

Comment: Your `print i, p[i]` statement is outside the while loop. `i` is in range entering the loop, but seems to go out of range inside the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

so, a few things..

Firstly, your code is very... unpythonic. This isn't C, so you don't need to use `while` loops for iteration, and don't use semicolons to separate multiple commands on one line in Python. Ever. Also, the `while`...`else` format is confusing and should be avoided.

If you look at the first few 'lines' of your `while` loop,

```
while i<len(p):
        l=[];i+=1
```

You keep `i` below the length of `p`, but you immediately increase `i`'s value by one. As such, when `i=len(p) - 1`, you will make `i` one larger, `len(p)`. So when you try to access `p[i]`, you are trying to access a value that doesn't exist.

Fixing those issues, you would get:

```
...
def splitMunipulation(p,threshold=5000):
    runs=[]

    for i in p:
        l=[]
        print i
        if i != press(0,1,0):
            runs.append(i)
    return runs
...

record=splitMunipulation(record)
```

Comment: I would add don't use the `while` . . . `else` construct. Even Guido has said it's a bad idea.

Comment: I just realized that this would cause an infinite loop if i was not equal to `press(0, 1, 0)`, so i substituted `if` for `while`. Should still give desired output... Looking at it now, I'm not really sure how this code is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

len returns the length, not the last index. If l=[1,2,3], then len(l) returns 3, but l[3] is out of range.

so you should use

```
while i<len(p)-1
```

or better yet:

```
for i in range(len(p)):
```

Comment: `while i < len(p): p[i]` is fine `while i <= len(p): p[i]` would throw and error. But @sqd's error is increment `i++` in between the two loops, so it would be like the above but with `p[i++]`

Comment: This should be avoided in Python, if you really need to get at the numbers, use `for i in enumerare(p)`

Comment: well,if i=3,than `i<3` is false.So the loop end